# Get tracking ID from shipment track event in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to get the tracking number from the `sales_order_shipment_track_save_after` event in Magento 1.9.0.1. For some reason the event does not seem to include the shipment, because `$observer->getEvent()->getShipment()` returns `NULL`. Am I using the wrong event?

These are the relevant parts of my code:

**config.xml (module)**

```
<events>
  <sales_order_shipment_track_save_after>
    <observers>
      <pixelstore_sms>
        <type>model</type>
        <class>pixelstore_sms/observer</class>
        <method>shipments</method>
      </pixelstore_sms>
    </observers>
  </sales_order_shipment_track_save_after>
</events>
```

**Observer.php (model)**

```
public function shipments($observer) {
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $shipment = $event->getShipment();
    if (!$shipment) {
        Mage::log('shipments event did not contain shipment', null, 'track.log');
        return false;
    }
    // We never reach this far
    $trackings = $shipment->getAllTracks();
    $tracking = end($trackings);
    $trackingId = $tracking->getNumber();
    // Here I would prefer to have the tracking ID in $trackingId
}
```

As you might have guessed, the `if` statement matches. `get_class()` shows that the observer is `Varien_Event_Observer`.

Am I observing the wrong event, or is there some other method I should call to get the tracking ID?

Comment: if you can get the order object you can call ->getTrackingNumbers() on it, infact if your observer inherits from Sales_Observer you can use getOrder()->getTrackingNumbers()

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a Sales_Observer, but Varien_Event_Observer. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that the event contains the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment_Track` object under the key `track`. This means I could get it from the event with `$event->getData('track')`, `$event['track']` or just `$event->getTrack()`. So this is what finally solved my problem:

```
public function shipments(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
  $event = $observer->getEvent();
  $track = $event->getTrack();
  $trackingId = $track->getNumber();

  // The shipment itself can be found in the track object,
  // and the order inside the shipment object:
  $shipment = $track->getShipment();
  $order = $shipment->getOrder();
}
```

It was all a misunderstanding about what was included in the actual event.

Answer (score 0):

It should be able to retrieve the order object even as the base observer.

```
public function shipments(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
$event = $observer->getEvent();
$shipment = $event->getShipment();
if (!$shipment) {
Mage::log('shipments event did not contain shipment', null, 'track.log');
return false;
}
// We never reach this far
$trackingId = $observer->getOrder()->getTrackingNumbers();
// Here I would prefer to have the tracking ID in $trackingId
}
```

Comment: This did not work for me. The observer did not contain the order object.

Comment: @EmilVikström same here, it makes a fatal error what cleong wrote.